# Achartengine bardiagrams with too high values

Tags: android, achartengine, diagram

I've worked large time with AChartEngine and now I know to plot a special bar diagram. Most of the bars are small. But two of them are much bigger than the others. If I use the function "setXAxisMax", the small bars are ridiculous small in the chart.

My question is, is there any way to plot the axis and some of the bars in two parts using ACharEngine? Or is it only possible to plot continuous bars?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need multiple y axes with `XYMultipleSeriesDataset`

Comment: Hello Stephan. Do you mean that I should paint so many X axis as I need? I didn't know that it is possible

Comment: You could look into implementing a logarithmic scaled y axis. I would clearly annotate the values for each bar though if you went that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also had the chance of using a few graphing engines and i haven't
 come across any that allows one to draw a single bar as two parts.In any case it will be very misleading when reading the values of the graphs.One solution which i use frequently would be to set a min value for the axis(y-axis) so that the values don't start from zero.that way you reduce the range significantly.